# Custom Keyboard Speech to text issue in IOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, speech, custom-keyboard

I am trying to build custom keyboard with speech to text feature using **Speech Framework** but I am facing issue in **`audioengine.start()`** It always failed in device but it is working on simulator fine.

Here is error:

> [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1544:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode,
>   kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561145187 audioEngine couldn't start
>   because of an error. The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error 561145187.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please cross check your code with below code.

```
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer? = SFSpeechRecognizer()
let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?

func recordAndRecognizeSpeech() {
    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    if recordingFormat.sampleRate > 0 {
        node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
            self.request.append(buffer)
        }
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
       // Speech Recognizer is not supported
        return
    }
    if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
        // Recognizer is not available right now
        return
    }


    request.shouldReportPartialResults = true

    // Create recognition task for given recognition request and retruns the result string on success
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request,
                                                        resultHandler: { (result, error) in
                                                            var isFinal = false
                                                            if result != nil {
                                                                var spokenWord = (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString ?? "")

                                                                isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
                                                            }

                                                            if error != nil || isFinal {
                                                                                                                             self.audioEngine.stop()
                                                            }
    })

}
```

Comment: I've checked with your code but getting same error:

[AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1544:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561145187
Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=561145187 "(null)" UserInfo={failed call=err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)}